# Delete an Azure Keyvault backed Scope in Databricks

Tags: azure-keyvault, azure-databricks

dbutils.secrets does not seem to have a method for deletion of any existing Azure Keyvault-backed Secret Scope in Databricks. 
[image]

Here is the documentation for creation and management of secret scopes in Databricks-
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/secrets/secret-scopes#akv-ss

The documentation does list a method to delete a Databricks-backed secret scope but none for a Keyvault-backed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:** There is no dbutils.secret command to delete the secret-scopes, you need to use the Databricks CLI to delete the scopes.

You can use the same command which is available in document to delete a Databricks backend managed scopes and Azure KeyVault Backend managed scopes.

```
databricks secrets delete-scope --scope <scope-name>
```

Here is the example for deleting scopes for Databricks Backend and Azure KeyVault Backend scopes.

[image]

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot use PowerShell for deleting the scopes. You can use Databricks CLI or REST API to delete the scopes.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Can't the REST API call be then made from Powershell?

Comment: @SA_95 of course. Powershell only needs some authentication method, e.g. a managed identity (only in dbrks premium plan) or a personal access token.